# Media upload error

Tags: images, uploads, errors

I'm new in WP development.

Suddenly I face upload error while media uploading.

Even I also deactivated all plugins. Now I'm using WP latest version (4.1).

After error msg the image is uploaded successfully (uploads/2014/12/image_name).but not listed in admin panel and also displays the error msg.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please show the error message (in an [edit] to your question). Also make sure that you use a default theme. And please tell us what you did that might cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

1. Rename your function.php file.
2. Now it works fine for other themes.
3. In my theme exactly the problem lies between the style tag.
4. remove style tags and then check your admin panel.

Thanks.